# User Account Settings in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, application-settings

I want to create a user account on first launch in a wizard and store that in a settings. Something like the account creation wizard in an email app. What is the best way to do?

Should I create a layout where I collect these inputs on first launch and store in Preferences?
A settings menu can be provided in the options key, so the Preferences can be edited.

Is that the right approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save user details in SharedPreference. Only concern should be security of passwords if you are saving it. Your application's shared preference is sandboxed by default, so your data is safe from other apps.. But a determined/inspired hacker with root access can get any data from any app in an android phone.

For password

1) Either you can use a web service, and store the password in server. During every login process, you can send the username/password to server and validate. This is the best approach if your application is using internet. This option has the simple advantage that you are not saving sensitive data on phone itself.

2) Other option is  to store password encrypted. You can use this option if your app doesn't use internet one bit, and you are not ready establish a server for authentication process. There  is no absolute security in Android, but saving encrypted does boost the security level.

Comment: Thanks. I plan to store the password in encrypted form in sqllite database. I want to provide a signup wizard during first launch and save the details in shared preferences and database. On Edit, preference screen will be shown. While all other fields are read from shared preferences, the password will be fetched from database.  My question is, Is there any layout for building the wizard or it has to be built manually with the fields, buttons and activities? Something like the wizard given by gmail app or K9 email app, where it has the next/back buttons with image.